# Windows Powershell: Rename all types of files in a folder with a specific patter

Tags: powershell

I have a few images and videos in a folder.

For eg assume my folder items current names are like this: a.png, b.png, c.png, d.mp4, e.png, f.mp4, g.png, h.mp4, i.png

I need to rename all the items in a specific pattern. My pattern is 20221115-item.

I am expecting an output like: 20221115-item-01.png, 20221115-item-02.png, 20221115-item-03.png, 20221115-item-04.mp4, 20221115-item-05.png, 20221115-item-06.mp4, 20221115-item-07.png, 20221115-item-08.pm4, 20221115-item-09.png

I tried to do this using Windows Power-shell and tried the below command.

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace “My”,”Our”}
```

But it only replace the file name `My` to `Our`.

I am very new to powershell. Is there any command to add new name with a specific pattern?

Comment: None of your source files have “my” and none of your expected names contain “our” - we are going to need a realistic example

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this

```
$folderPath = "Insert_folder_path_here" #all items in this folder will be renamed
$prefix = "20221115"
$i = 1

# Get all files in the directory 
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Set the new name for the file(s)
        $newName = "{0}-{1}-{2:D2}{3}" -f $prefix, $_.BaseName, $i++, $_.Extension
        
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
    }
```

Lets say one of the items is named "Holiday.png", then this script will rename it to "20221115-Holiday-01" (01 if it is the first file). If you want the name to be "20221115-item-01" and not use the current name, then replace

```
$newName = "{0}-{1}-{2:D2}{3}" -f $prefix, $_.BaseName, $i++, $_.Extension
```

with

```
$newName = "{0}-item-{1:D2}{2}" -f $prefix, $i++, $_.Extension
```

**Note that this script renames everything in the folder you specify as $folderPath so please test this in a test folder first to see if this gets the result you want.**
Also, before running the script in the desired folder you can add -whatif after the Rename-Item command to see what it would do without it actually making changes:

```
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName -WhatIf
```

Af for how the script works, you first specify the folder the items are in and you give information for the naming of the files ($i = 1 tells the script it should count starting from 1).

It gets all items in the folder specified and run a ForEach loop to run the code between { and } for all the items that it finds with Get-ChildItem.

$newName sets the naming convention for the files. "{0}-{1}-{2:D2}{3}" corrolates with -f $prefix, $*.BaseName, $i++, $*.Extension so that {0} is $prefix, {1} is $_.BaseName, etc. This determines that the name will be 20221115-Holiday-01.

20221115 is the prefix {1}. Holiday in this example is the $*.BaseName (the current name of the file) {2}. $i++ is the number given and it counts +1 per file {2:D2} (D2 specifies that it should count using 2 numbers, so that ensures you get 01, 02 instead of 1,2). $*.Extension {3} ensures that a .png file will remain a .png file etc.

Rename-Item is the command that actually changes the file names and it uses the content of the $newName variable to do so.

Comment: I am new to powershell, should I run the renaming command as a single line? I tried like below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVh3l.png

Comment: You are getting an error because Rename-Item should have its own seperate line. It might work with a pipeline ( | ) before rename-item, but I would recommend pasting the code in Powershell ISE and running it from there instead of the normal Powershell app. ISE will make it easier to read and execute scripts with multiple lines of code. In ISE you can copy paste the code in the same format as I posted it in and run it that way. Remember to use -WhatIf and/or use a test folder first to ensure it does what you want.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyrmM.png

Comment: Getting the above output when i try with powershell Ise

Comment: Something is wrong with the $newName variable. You can try copy pasting the entire script from my post again to ensure the formatting is correct. Also make sure at the $folderPath variable that the path of the folder the items are in is pasted in between the quotationmarks at "Insert_folder_path_here". You can use "Test-Path $folderPath" (run without quotationmarks) as a seperate command to test is your path variable is correct. It should give "True" as output.
If it still doesn't work, please share the full script how you entered it (you can change the path for the screenshot) and the error.